# WP returns to domain root instead of siteurl

Tags: url-rewriting, site-url, home-url, routing

On various admin actions (e.g. delete a post), my fresh WP install (`dev.mydomain.com/website`) returns to the domain root (`dev.mydomain.com`) instead of `dev.mydomain.com/website/wp-admin/edit.php?some-vars-here`.

I've setup the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` to the correct site url, but no difference. Site runs over ssl on Apache (I've added the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` = 'on' to `wp-config.php`).

I am able to browse the complete wp-admin and the post is deleted on a delete action, but just jumps to the wrong url after completion. I feel like I'm forgetting something dumb here... any clues?

UPDATE

`.htaccess` is present (was created by WP) and has `RewriteBase /website/`

Comment: Have you updated your .htaccess? looks like your site is in a subfolder and not on the hosting root (not in `public_html` or `www`)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that .htaccess has the correct `RewriteBase /website/`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that mod_rewrite is loaded and enabled. If you're not sure, there are plenty of resources on the web with tips on how to check if mod_rewrite is working in your environment. If it is enabled, then check to make sure Apache is set up to allow the use of a .htaccess file for your environment - `AllowOverride` may be set to `None` (should be set to `All`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is all true, mod_rewrite is loaded and the .htaccess is read